# Opposite Collatz Conjecture

Tags: integer-sequence, rounding

I'm trying to explore what would happen if you change the collatz conjecture to flip the equations for odds and evens.  So if you have an even number you multiply by 3, add 1, and divide by 2.  If you have an odd number, divide it by 2.  I understand that this will leave you with some decimal answers so I'm deciding to round up.  I'm trying to write this program in *Mathematica* however am running into trouble.  Here is my code:

```
flipCollatz[n_] := If[EvenQ[n], ((3 n + 1)/2), (n/2)]
flipOrbit[n_] := Module[{flipVals = {n}, n0 = n},
  While[n0 > 1,
   n0 = flipCollatz[n0];
   If[IntegerQ[n0], n0 = n0, n0 = (n0 + 0.5)];
   flipVals = Append[flipVals, n0];
   ];
  flipVals
  ]
flipOrbit[10]
```

It's giving me the wrong output.  I should be getting 10,16,25,13,7,4,7,4,...

Any ideas?

Thanks much!

Comment: With n=10 it follows that 10*3+1 /2 = 15.5.  My If statement should then add .5 making it 16.  So that's {10, 16}.  Now take 16 * 3 + 1 / 2 = 24.5.  Add .5 again to get 25.  So {10,16,25}.  25/2 = 12.5 + .5 = 13.  You see?

Comment: Be aware `IntegerQ` gives false on a floating value: On second pass you have `8.` which is *not an integer* so becomes `8.5`

Comment: Simply using `1/2` instead of `.5` makes this work. Beware however it never converges so your `While` loop never exits.

Comment: ..and the `1/2` turns out to be *always* needed so just do `If[EvenQ[n], ((3 n + 1)/2), (n/2)] + 1/2` ..

Answer (score 3):

wrap the RHS of your flipCollatz with the `Ceiling` function

```
flipCollatz[n_] := Ceiling[If[EvenQ[n], ((3 n + 1)/2), (n/2)]]
```

[Ceiling](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bn52pe-o2m) rounds up to the nearest integer

---

```
NestList[flipCollatz, 10, 7]
```

> {10, 16, 25, 13, 7, 4, 7, 4}

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
f[n_] := With[{l = Boole[EvenQ@n]}, 
  l Ceiling[(3 n + 1)/2] + (1 - l) Ceiling[n/2]]
rc[n_] := NestWhileList[f, n, UnsameQ, All]
grf[n_] := Module[{set = rc /@ Range[n]},
  Union[DirectedEdge @@@ Join @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ set)]]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 Graph[grf[p], VertexLabels -> label, VertexSize -> vertex, 
  VertexStyle -> vc, GraphLayout -> embedding, ImageSize -> 600],
 {p, {20, 30, 100, 1000}}, {vertex, 0.1, 
  2}, {vc, {Blue, 
   LightBlue}}, {embedding, {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", 
   "CircularEmbedding"}}, {label, {None, Placed["Name", Center]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to show you how to write your code in a functional style more suitable to *Mathematica*.

```
flipCollatz[k_Integer?OddQ] := Quotient[k, 2] + 1 
flipCollatz[k_Integer?EvenQ] := Quotient[3 k, 2] + 1

flipOrbit[n_Integer?(# > 1 &), max : _Integer?(# > 1 &) : 12] := 
   NestWhileList[flipCollatz, n, {#1, #2} != {4, 7} &, 2, max]
Column @ Table[flipOrbit[n], {n, 2, 15}]
```

[image: table]

The second argument of `flipOrbit` limits the loop to `max` steps. It has a default value of 12, which I used in generating the table of results.